# Django POST validated fields disappearing (NOT NULL constraint failed)

Tags: python, django, rest, post, notnull

I have a Django project with some models. The one which is giving me trouble is this one:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    patient = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=False, blank=False)
    how = MultiSelectField(choices=HOW_CHOICES, default=1)
    with_who = MultiSelectField(choices=WITH_WHO_CHOICES, default=1)
    accessories = MultiSelectField(choices=ACCESSORIES, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=False, blank=False)
    scheduled = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    arrived = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    started = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    completed = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    scheduled_end = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    detected_end = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    area_start = models.ForeignKey(Area, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, related_name='jobs_start')
    area_end = models.ForeignKey(Area, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, related_name='jobs_end')
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    worker = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='jobs_worker')
```

I have this URL to GET, POST, PUT and DELETE.

```
router.register(r'jobs', views.JobList)
```

The view linked to inherits from ModelViewSet:

```
class JobList(LoginRequiredMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Job.objects.all()
    serializer_class = JobsSerializer
```

For my understanding, simply by inheriting from ModelViewSet the API handles GET, POST and PUT by default. That's probably why in the web API I see the form with the data to POST ([see this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eu3h1.png)). The view handles the GET perfectly, but the problem comes at the POST request.

As you can see in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eu3h1.png), there are only 3 fields to be filled for the POST data. But in the model I have more fields declared `null=False` which are different from the ones in the POST data box. So, one question would be:

- Where does the API get the information of the required fields to show?

If I try the POST, I get this error:
`NOT NULL constraint failed: job_manager_job.area_end_id`

I added the *create()* functions to the view and the serializer in order to debug the API process. At this point I added manually some of the fields required for the Job to be created ([see this other screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTX58.png)). As you can see, I added the same value in two similar keys, which brings me to another question:

- Which keys does the JSON expect? the field names of the model or the fields in the serializer?

The view looks like this:

```
class JobList(LoginRequiredMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Job.objects.all()
    serializer_class = JobsSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        json_data = request.data
        job_serializer = self.serializer_class(data=json_data)
        if job_serializer.is_valid():
            job_serializer.save()
            print("valid data")
        pass
```

And the serializer like this:

```
class JobsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    status = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_status')
    area_from = serializers.StringRelatedField(source='area_start.name', default=None)
    area_to = serializers.StringRelatedField(source='area_end.name', default=None)
    assigned = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_assigned')
    info = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_info')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print(validated_data)
        Job.objects.create(**validated_data)
        pass


    def get_status(self, a_job):
        if a_job.approved:
            return 'Approved'
        if a_job.completed:
            return 'Completed'
        if a_job.started:
            return 'Started'
        if a_job.arrived:
            return 'Arrived'
        if a_job.scheduled:
            return 'Scheduled'
        if a_job.created:
            return 'Created'
        return 'Defined'

    def get_info(self, a_job):
        return get_job_info_options(a_job)

    def get_assigned(self, a_job):
        try:
            a = a_job.worker.first_name + ' ' + a_job.worker.last_name
        except AttributeError:
            a = None
        return a

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ['pk', 'status', 'scheduled', 'scheduled_end', 'assigned', 'area_from', 'area_to', 'patient', 'info']
```

The problem is that in the debugger I see that the view receives all the JSON data (including the extra keys) which are passed to the serializer in `self.serializer_class(data=json_data)` but the *validated_data* in the serializer includes only the 3 keys that are shown in the POST box.I don't know how this data disappeared in the serializer.
Check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89UDF.png) to see that the `data={...}` of the serializer is different to the `validated_data` in the *create* function

I will appreciate a lot not only solving this problem but also if anyone could answer the questions above regarding how django works internally.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: One cause for sure is that SerializerMethodField is read_only, so won't ever end up in validated_data, but that doesn't cover everything. Can you show a `repr(serializer)` with valid data? It seems it decides some fields are read_only or just plain removes them.

Comment: @Melvyn thanks for your quick interest. I used SerializerMethodField because the "status" of a Job is not an attribute of the model and it's "computed" when the view gets a GET request. The repr of the serializer is in the text box of the last screenshot. But the fields that use SerializerMethodField in the serializer are not required in the POST. The ones needed are area_start and area_end (which are foreign keys).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look:

```
fields = [
    'pk',  # unused in create
    'status',  # on serializer, read only method field
    'scheduled',  # OK
    'scheduled_end',  # OK
    'assigned',  # on serializer, read only method field
    'area_from',  # on serializer, read only string related field
    'area_to',  # on serializer, read only string related field
    'patient',  # OK
    'info'  # on serializer, read only method field
]
```

I got 3 OK's, so I think DRF is correct :)

Questions:

- Where does the API get the information of the required fields to show?

All writeable fields that are in serializer.Meta.fields end up in the form. They don't have to be required in order for the form to render them.

- Which keys does the JSON expect? the field names of the model or the fields in the serializer?

Field name of the serializer. But to be more accurate, [Parsers are first in the pipeline](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/), which allows you to [send camelCase json and get snake_case in validated data](https://github.com/vbabiy/djangorestframework-camel-case).

The simplest solution to your problem is [PrimaryKeyRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield). This means consumer needs to remember primary keys, but [SlugRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) can keep things readable.

Comment: wow! I didn't know that StringRelatedField were read-only. So the problem comes from the definition of the serializer... So what can I do to make the area_start and area_end not read-only (since they are needed for the creation of the Job).
And thanks a lot! Given your knowledge in django, would you mind answering the bullet point questions that I posted? Thanks!